# Passing variables to .swf while using UILoader

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am using `UILoader` to load a .swf file. My .swf file takes a querystring parameter, like `myapp.swf?id=12344`

Now, when I specify the source for the UILoader in the other project as `"myapp.swf?id=12344"`, I am getting the following error:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.
```

I am trying to load an swf that takes some query-string parameters in another swf. I am loading `UILoader` to do that. How else can I do this so it will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work with or without URL parameters, first make it work WITHOUT parameters to be sure you are calling the correct URL: for instance `/myapp.swf?id=12344` and `myapp.swf?id=12344` can point to different location depending on your environment.